# rosanswers formatting

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey I have another question but this comes first, how can I paste some xml code here to format my question? I've tried the 101010 thing but it still deletes a big chunk of the code within < / node > tags

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270916/rosanswers-formatting/) by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2017-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you copy and pasting it? In my experience, it's easiest to copy and paste the code into the text box, highlight it, then click the `101010` button (or hit `Ctrl-k`). Don't click the button first, that usually only works for very small bits of code.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2